# Pass child object to function which requires parent object

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I have a class Spaceship, which has the function with the following signature:
`public function CheckMissileHit(enemies:Vector.<Spaceship>):void`

I inherited `Spaceship` class by `EnemySpaceship`. Now, my old code utilizes the function above as follows:
`mPlayer.CheckMissileHit(mEnemySpaceships)`

Originally, `mEnemySpaceships` was `Vector.<Spaceship>`, but now I want to utilize some OOP concepts and created separate class called `EnemySpaceship`.

But unfortunately, if I pass `Vector.<EnemySpaceship>` to the function, which requires `Vector.<Spaceship>`, I'm screwed. One of the base principles of OOP is polymorphism, so how can I produce it in AS3? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no relation between Vectors parameterized with different types in Actionscript. Unfortunately, there's nothing you can really do about this. There's no equivalent like Java's `List<? extends Spaceship>`.

Why not just use `Vector.<Spaceship>` and fill it with EnemySpaceships?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the definition of the function. I.e.:

```
public function CheckMissileHit(enemies:Vector.<Spaceship>):void
```

Should be

```
public function CheckMissileHit(enemies:*):void
```

This change will make your code passing the compilation. I'm not sure, but if EnemySpaceship inherits Spaceship it should be possible to pass Vector.<EnemySpaceship> with no problems.